# I want to update picture using function but it always says Future<dynamic> is not a sub type of type ImageProvider<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I want to update picture using function but it always says Future is not a sub type of type ImageProvider.

Function is following function it'll call by Image provider in the widget tree.It works perfectly when using ImageFile which is pick from Image provider.But I copied that file in to disk and retrieve it doesn't work.

```
 _decideImageView(){
  if(imageFile== null){
    return AssetImage("assets/example.jpeg");
  }else{
  return AssetImage('$_localPath/name.jpg');
}
```

Working one

```
_decideImageView(){
  if(imageFile== null){
    return AssetImage("assets/example.jpeg");
  }else{
    return FileImage(imageFile);
  }

}
```

Image pick by this function.

```
_openGallery(BuildContext context) async{

  var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  this.setState((){
    imageFile = picture;
  });

  Directory pathd = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path =pathd.path;
  final File newImage = await imageFile.copy('$path/name.jpg');
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

I have provide application directory to main.dart by using

```
static final _localPath = getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Comment: you are missing a await keyword somewhere

Comment: post full stacktrace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out the [documentation for getApplicationDocumentsDirectory](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationDocumentsDirectory.html). If you check it out, you will see that it returns a `Future<Directory>`. The app cannot know if you have resolved the future while running synchronously so it throws an error.

A solution to have futures resolved before calling them, is using `initState` like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((directory) {
        _localPath = directory;
    });
}
```

I recommend you reading about Async programming as it is quite interesting to know. I hope this helps you and you can develop your app further!

Comment: I think can't use async with initState

Comment: True, sorry I usually write faster than I think, eventhough you cannot await in initState, you can use then. Check the edit.